# How to make CSS NOT do something

Tags: css, css-content

is it possible to make css NOT do something?

example:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol.someClassname {
    NOT counter-reset: item;
}
```

I KNOW that you should just switch the classes to make it work. It's not really an issue, I was just wondering if it could work, thanks

Comment: How does the browser know what to do if you just tell them "Not to do something"? You can reset it to its standard behaviour

Comment: What you're asking is something that shouldn't have to be done, or is avoided by utilizing best practices in most circumstances.  In the few situations where you need to do something like this, you simply perform a "reset" by setting the property to it's default value.  For example setting a border from border: 1px solid #000; to border: none;  Common values for most properties are either none, initial or inherit.

Comment: Based on your comments I've closed this as a duplicate. I had originally perceived this as a *"how can you disable a `counter-reset` property"*, but it appears this is more of an *"is there a CSS not equals selector"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CSS specifications

> The :not pseudo-class represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

So in your example, this:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.someClassname {
  NOT counter-reset: item;
}
```

Becomes this:

```
ol:not(.someClassName) {
  counter-reset: item;
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah, so this says All ol besides the one with (.someClassName) will be counter-reset right?

Comment: @user3712713 Yeah, exactly. But this is the **right** way to do it :)

Comment: @RandomUser the *right* way to do it? Why is this any more correct than the way my answer does it?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly this is part of the css specification, that's why. Otherwise they do the same thing and your version is also more common

Comment: Right, this is what i was looking for. Thanks!

I guess both answers are right, @RandomUser made the entire "function" NOT do something,

James' answer changed the option to NOT do something.. so it depends which you need, just that option or everything

Comment: @RandomUser what do you mean "part of the CSS specification"? Setting a `counter-reset` declaration to `none` is also part of the CSS specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-reset. I don't see what that has to do with it though?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly look, I'm not saying your answer is wrong, its just that your answer uses a hack from the time when :not didn't exist. And now that it does, we should start using it right?

Comment: It's also worth adding that `:not()` will not work on IE7 or IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), whereas setting `counter-reset` to `none` will (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters). If you have to cater for a wide range of browsers, this solution isn't the *right* way to do it, it's just a slightly more convenient method for modern browsers with decent CSS3 support.

Comment: @RandomUser how is it a *hack* to set `counter-reset` to `none`? It's a property defined by the CSS specification specifically to turn off such a property. That isn't a hack. Giving a latter selector higher specificity in order to override properties also isn't a hack, it's common practice and has been for years. I'm not claiming that you're saying my answer is wrong, I'm just wondering why you think this is the "*right* way to do it".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly like I said, it's part of the new spec and is supported on all major browsers and IE9

Comment: @JamesDonnelly it's the right way to do it because, simply, it's supposed to replace the "set a property to none" method and its much shorter. Can this debate end now?

Comment: @RandomUser `:not()` was actually added to the CSS Level 3 Selectors Specification on October 26th 2001 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-selectors-20010126) - 13 years ago. It's far from new. ;-)

Comment: @RandomUser if you can find me the documentation which states that `:not()` should be used in place of setting a value to `none`, `initial` or `unset` then I'd be more than happy to read it. Otherwise this answer is no more *right* than my own.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Okay, which means you should have used :not too!

Comment: @RandomUser but why? The `counter-reset` property wouldn't have a `none` value if CSS wasn't intended to be used this way.

Comment: Ladies, please, you're both pretty. You're both right, now settle down.

Answer (score 5):

You can set it to [`none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-reset):

```
ol.someClassname {
    counter-reset: none;
}
```

This will make the `counter-reset` not do anything on the matched selector.

Comment: Well, this answered my example but not quite my question unless.. Does every CSS option have a "none" feature also though?

Comment: @user3712713 I'm not sure how this hasn't answered your question? Not every CSS declaration has a `none` value, but almost all of them can be *reset* with either `initial`, `unset` or `none`.